# Delete disabled triggers from Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I know it is possible to create a trigger:

```js
function testTriggers()
{
  var now = new Date();
  now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + 1);

  ScriptApp.newTrigger("bingo").timeBased().at(now).create();
}
```

And once the trigger runs, it will be marked as `Disabled`.

[image]

I know you can get all triggers:

```js
ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()
```

But I can't find a way to identify which triggers are disabled so I can delete just those triggers.

I need to find the disabled triggers so I can then create more triggers.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61383100) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [programmatically disable / enable Google Apps Script script trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974038/programmatically-disable-enable-google-apps-script-script-trigger)

Comment: @IrvinJayG. No. Mine is asking about deleting a trigger once the google back-end disables it after execution.

Comment: @TheMaster Not really. I don't want to delete the trigger when it runs. I want to delete through some ad-hoc process. But there doesn't seem to be a mechanism to find disabled triggers.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan You're right. I don't think there is such a mechanism. My answer is probably the closest you're looking for. Another workaround is to store the trigger id when trigger is created in props. And delete all triggers associated with a id in props later on.

Comment: Sounds like you've already figured out that what you want does not exist so why not go make it a feature request and move on.

Comment: @Cooper I mean, I will but I posted this to first confirm I am not missing something. Could you imagine how messy it would be if everyone just posted a feature request for something just cause **they can't find a way to do it**? I'm not sure what problem you have with me asking....

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks! If you want to answer this question with then then I can accept it.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/208980827 If anyone wants to help me out by upvoting it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there isn't a way to identify disabled triggers. This feature is requested by OP:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/208980827

Kindly add a star to the issue, if you want Google developers to implement this request.

#### Possible workarounds:

- [Delete the trigger when the function is triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61383100)
- Save the trigger id as a `key` in properties, when the trigger is created. When the trigger function is triggered, add a disabled marker as `value` to the triggerid `key` in properties. Then you may deleted all disabled triggers later.
- Manually delete all disabled triggers from  the dashboard.